# Android Studio Navigation Error - New Windows in Background

Tags: android-studio, android-navigation

I am having a weird error with Android Studio. When I am navigating through the software, new windows tend to appear in the background rather than the foreground. This inconvenience is making it extremely difficult to navigate. Any ideas what setting is causing this? In some instances, it is preventing me from progressing.

I have included a screenshot of the issue. You can see that my "Browse Repositories" is behind the "Plugins." In cases where the new dialog window is smaller than the original, I am unable to proceed (since I can't even see the new dialog).[image]

Comment: I noted that this is occurring when the window is maximized, so not sure if it is a Mac setting, I am running El Capitan. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

A workaround is to avoid maximizing the screen. Reports have been sent via the official Google Android forums, so we will see if a fix is implemented.

Comment: This is not a solution its a workaround, I really like to have the window maximized

Comment: Do you experience the same issue?

Comment: Yes, and there is bugs added https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=192746